# Deleting rows in Oracle: evaluating vs. executing

Tags: oracle, delete-row

When I run a `DELETE` command in Oracle, it does all of the should-I-delete-this-row evaluation *before* it *performs* any deletion, right?  That's well-defined Oracle behavior, right?

For example, if I have a table `ATABLE` with numeric `ID` and alphanumeric `VALUE` columns, and three rows with different IDs but all the same VALUE, and I run this command ...

```
delete from ATABLE A1
where exists (select * from ATABLE A2
where A1.VALUE = A2.VALUE and A1.ID <> A2.ID);
```

... then it deletes *all three rows*.  To me that indicates evaluate-evaluate-evaluate, delete-delete-delete.  If it were evaluate-delete, evaluate-delete, evaluate-delete, then there would be one row remaining at the end, because it would have no row to match with.

Again, just checking that the theory matches the practice here.  Thank you.

Comment: That's the main difference between ROWSET logic and PROCEDURAL logic: SQL is a ROWSET-based, e.g. it doesn't loop re-evaluating subquery for each main row.

Comment: From the Concepts, [Data Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-5F42279D-EE21-4722-9C4A-F24147B16F12): *Oracle Database always enforces statement-level read consistency, which **guarantees** that the data that a single query returns is committed and consistent **for a single point in time**. Depending on the transaction isolation level, this point is the time **at which the statement was opened or the time the transaction began**.*

Comment: It doesn't evaluate first, because it works differently under the hood (reads old data from undo segment), but every expression defined in a plain SQL statement is evaluated regarding the same point in time: this is the same for `sysdate`, for example, `delete/update` modified rows etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I have a table `ATABLE` with numeric `ID` and alphanumeric `VALUE` columns, and three rows with different `ID`s but all the same `VALUE`, and I run this command ...
>
> ```sql
> delete from ATABLE A1
> where exists (select * from ATABLE A2
> where A1.VALUE = A2.VALUE and A1.ID <> A2.ID);
> ```
>
> ... then it deletes all three rows.

Yes, but you can test that yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE atable (id, value) AS
SELECT LEVEL + 0, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL + 3, 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL + 4, 3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Then the table contains:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |

If you run your `DELETE` query then, after the `DELETE` the table will contain:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |

All the duplicate `VALUE` rows are deleted.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8h__jYlQ)